# Sending the id via form

Tags: php, html

I have created a forum where people send questions and get answers like here. So that, when a user answers a question in a form that i created, i send the id of the question to another php file, to store the answer to the right place, as below.

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $id_of_question;?>" style="display:none;"/>
```

But i think this is not safer method to do that or there should be better ways to do it. So, my question is whether my method is good or safe? How can i do better? I think what i did above is lazy way:)
Thanks

Comment: you must sanitize the form, use mysql_escape_string, this will ensure some amount of safety!

Comment: @sree: you have absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @zerkms please let me know what is wrong in my comment?

Comment: @sree: 1. `mysql_escape_string` completely irrelevant to php and html 2. `mysql_real_escape_string` is a correct one, not `mysql_escape_string` 3. `mysql_real_escape_string` not about security, but about composing *syntactically correct* query (and nothing more)

Comment: @zerkms dont mistake me.. but isnt that one of the safer method to pass the php variable through? which i tot was his concern..

Comment: @sree: to pass it where?

Comment: @yes mysql_real_escape_string not mysql_escape_string agreed.. and pass variable through mysql_real_escape_string...

Comment: @sree: for what *exact* reason? What do you want to protect from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16404/discussion-between-zerkms-and-sree)

Comment: @zerkms tnx but i cant join right now... we ll continue this later and perhaps i can learn from u.. tnx again

Comment: @sree: ping me here or in email (can be found in my cv in profile) if you keen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `input type="hidden"` would make more sense, but that makes no practical difference as far as security is concerned.

While a user could change the value of the field, you just have to make sure that the value submitted is sane.

i.e. at the most basic level that it is for a question that exists.

If you have more complicated requirements (e.g. some questions may be closed and not accept new answers) then you need to change that the question is open as well.

There is no way to force the browser to submit a particular value. All your security must be enforced on the server.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with it, but use `hidden` instead:

```
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $id_of_question;?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no security issues as long as your checking the value on the other side. I would be at least be checking to see if the value is an int on the other side such as `is_int($_GET['id'])`, you can go further to also check that it is a valid id but that would be expensive for your DB.

The reason it really isn't an issue is that theres a 99% chance the ID is in your URL anyway, so it's not like your giving out any secrets.

Answer (score 0):

Not `text` but `hidden`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_of_question;?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think its better to use the hidden property rather than css.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_of_question;?>" />
```

I have been using this in my websites for a long time. But yea there might be some better ways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also

```
<form name="form" action="formSubmitUrl.php?id=<?php echo $id ;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;" />
</form>
```

and u can check the post and get value of the form..